# I am trying to arrange strings in alphabetical order that user inputs randomly, but nothing shows

Tags: c#

I am trying to do this using the `String.Compare()` method and my conditions are that if the methods finds out that the upcoming word is alphabetically behind the current word, their position changes with the help of the temporary string `strWordTemp`.

The code seems fine, and when the last number is reached, I have written another block of code to make sure that it is being compared with the word behind it instead of in front of it. All seems good, but when I want this to show, nothing shows. The screen is blank, no errors show either.

```
for (int intI = 0; intI < strWordList.Length; intI++)
{
    while (intI != strWordList.Length)
    {
        intComparison = string.Compare(strWordList[intI], strWordList[intI + 1]);
        if (intComparison > 0)
        {
            strWordTemp = strWordList[intI];
            strWordList[intI] = strWordList[intI + 1];
            strWordList[intI + 1] = strWordTemp;
        }
    }
    if (intI == strWordList.Length)
    {
        intComparison = string.Compare(strWordList[intI - 1], strWordList[intI]);
        if (intComparison > 0)
        {
            strWordTemp = strWordList[intI - 1];
            strWordList[intI - 1] = strWordList[intI];
            strWordList[intI] = strWordTemp;
        }
    }
}

for (int intI = 0; intI < strWordList.Length; intI++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Word #" + (intI + 1) + " is: " + strWordList[intI]);
}
```

Comment: The Syntax is too similar... which langangue is this, C# or Java?

Comment: "try to use similar codes, as my class will not allow advanced coding" -- Translation: I'm going to try to pass your work off as my own, so if you could blend it in and make that easier for me, that would be awesome of you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 oops... I guessed Java, didn't think of C#...

Comment: No, this is *definitely* C#.  `System.Console.WriteLine` doesn't exist in my lexicon.

Comment: @Makoto I don't know Java well enough to know that for certain, but I thought that was the case.  Thanks for confirming

Comment: Is this still okay for SO or is this already something to close?

Comment: @DanielBrückner someone else might feel differently, but now that we have a language, it seems to be at least answerable, so I won't vote to close it.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Aside from the OP's demanding tone, it seems like a reasonable question to me as well, now that the language is given.

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite loop in your code:

```
    while (intI != strWordList.Length)
    {
        intComparison = string.Compare(strWordList[intI], strWordList[intI + 1]);
        if (intComparison > 0)
        {
            strWordTemp = strWordList[intI];
            strWordList[intI] = strWordList[intI + 1];
            strWordList[intI + 1] = strWordTemp;
        }
    }
```

Neither `intI` nor `strWordList.Length` changes within loop and there is no `break` statement, so it's going to run forever.

Comment: Thanks bro, makes sense. I lost my common sense. LOL